# Low performance processing a DataArray obtained from quantiles (xarray)

Tags: python-xarray

I've noticed very low performances when processing a DataArray obtained from the built-in xarray quantile function applied on a chunked DataArray. It takes much longer to access/plot values than for any other DataArray of the same size/chunk pattern.

As example:
I've included a small script comparing plotting time of two 2D DataArrays derived from a same 3D sample random DataArray: a time slice, and quantiles computed over time.
The script execution time difference is important although both arrays are of the same size and chunking pattern, and contain the same type of data.

(It took me 30+ minutes to plot a single quantile for my whole study dataset, whereas the sliced data plot took <1 minute). I haven't found yet any useful information that might help me to solve this issue.

Thanks for reading !

The following script shows the execution time difference noted when plotting two DataArrays of the same size, the first one obtained from slicing and the second one from the xarray built-in quantile function:
(xarray version 2023.7.0)

```
# start of code
# module import
import xarray as xr
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# sample data
test = xr.DataArray(data=np.random.rand(500,500,500),
                  coords={"x": list(range(500)), "y": list(range(500)), 'time':list(range(500))},
                  dims=("x", "y", 'time')).chunk('auto')

test1 = test.sel(time=0)
test2 = test.chunk(dict(time=-1)).quantile(0.5, dim='time', skipna=True)

# plot of test1 + time
start = datetime.datetime.now()
plt.figure()
test1.plot()
end = datetime.datetime.now()
time_taken = end - start
print('time taken for plotting test1', time_taken)

# plot of test2 + time
start = datetime.datetime.now()
plt.figure()
test2.plot()
end = datetime.datetime.now()
time_taken = end - start
print('time taken for plotting test2', time_taken)
```